# How to convert [id] to [slug] url in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on nextjs and i have "blog" list and after click on blog,page redirect to "blog detail page" And current url is like

```
"http://localhost:3001/29"
```

Which is working fine,But i want my url should be like

```
http://localhost:3001/slug/posttitle
```

My current code for "Link" is which is working fine

```
<Link href={{pathname: "/[id]",query: { id: post.id },}}>
```

But for change "id" to "slug" in url,i tried with following code

```
<Link href={{pathname: "/[slug]",query: { title: post.title },}}>
```

But my url convert to `"http://localhost:3001/[slug]?id=myslug"`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `example.com/post-slug` as the URL since the slug is usually generated from the post title anyways? From what I understand, your root "/" page is already your blog section which contains all your blog posts previews. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ivanatias you are right, let me explain , in "Main/Home" page with use of "component" i am fetching blog listing and now want to show "blog details"

Comment: Note that if your page is named `[slug].js` then you should pass `post.title` in the `slug` query parameter, i.e. `<Link href={{pathname: "/[slug]", query: { slug: post.title }}}>`.